# Angular app skip one of the pages while browserback click

Tags: angular, browser-history, popstate

I have a component **before-adetail** which has a link to another component **a-detail** which again has a link to **a-review** which again has a link to **a-confirm**.

So the flow is **before-adetail**->**a-detail**->**a-review**->**a-confirm**

**before-adetail.component.html**:

```
<p>before-adetail works!</p>
<a routerLink="/detail">A-detail</a>
```

**a-detail**:

```
<p>a-detail works!</p>
<a routerLink="/review">A-review</a>
```

**a-review**:

```
<p>a-review works!</p>
<a routerLink="/confirm">A-confirm</a>
```

**a-confirm**:

```
<p>a-confirm works!</p>
```

So when I first run the app **new tab** is stored in history. Say I run the app on localhost:4200. Then, when i click on the link in **before-adetail** this is also stored in history and so on.

If I press a browser back button from **a-review** page, it goes back to **a-detail** page, and if i press the back button again, it goes to **before-adetail**.

But what I want to achieve is if i have visited **a-review** and press back button, it should go to **a-detail** and when i press back again it shouldnt go to **before-adetail** but whatever page is before that in the history.

I want this functionality only if i have visited **a-review** page, If i haven't it should work the normal way that it was working.

How do I achieve this?

**What I have tried right now:**
Inside **a-review.component.ts**

```
location.onPopState(() => {
      const temporaryUrl = window.location.href;
      const url = temporaryUrl.replace('/review', '/detail');
      history.pushState('a-review', '', url);
    });
  }
```

Passed **a-review** to know that the browser back has been clicked from **a-review** page

And inside **a-detail.component.ts**

```
location.onPopState(() => {
      if (history.state === 'a-review') {
        history.go(-2);
      }
    });
  }
```

This does achieve what I am trying to do, but for a split second like 1 second or two seconds, even the **before-adetail** page is visible which i dont want.

What is the way to improve this or what are other better ways to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would propose you to use replaceUrl

```
<p>a-review works!</p>
<a routerLink="/confirm" [replaceUrl]="true">A-confirm</a>
```

what it does is when you click "A-confirm" the current history state('/review' path) will be replaced with '/confirm' one. and "Back" button will bring you back to '/detail' directly